# Check source that post request was sent from

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, url, post

So I have a js script located at https://ad.aakhilv.me/config.js, and it sends a post request via a script tag on the browser to my server and this function parses it:

```js
app.post("/new", cors, async (req, res) => {
  // Parses data sent here.
});
```

However, some people are customizing the script and changing up the data that is supposed to be sent. Anyone know if there is a way that I can make sure that the request was sent through the script url that I provided above, and not a modified version of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real way to do that. Anyone, anywhere, at any time, can make a post request to "/new".

What you need to do is verify the data that the route recieves on the backend. For example, if you want to make sure that only user is changing their data, and not somebody elses data, then you want to use session cookies to verify that they are logged in.

Ultimately, your backend code has to assume that users will abuse or otherwise try to take advantage of that route if they can. Your code inside that `app.post` should be able to verify that no malicious data is being sent, and that it is from the proper user.

Comment: I see, because some people were using it to imposter other websites such as google.com or reddit.com.